# CrossAppNavigation generate the wrong URL for the route

Tags: sandbox, sap-fiori, sap-business-technology-platform

Route from App1 to App2`s detail page using a parameter using CrossAppNavigation it formats the URL wrong for me.

I have 2 navigations from App1 to App2

1. From App1 to Main Page of App2
2. From App1 to Detail Page of App2 using an ID.

The first one work just fine because the url of APP1s main page looks like http://localhost:4004/index.html#test.app-display

```
sap.ushell.Container.getService("CrossApplicationNavigation").toExternal({
    target: {
      crossAppNav: true,
      semanticObject: "test.app",
      action: "display"
    },
  });
```

The second one doesn t work because of "action property "

That should be the link http://localhost:4004/index.html#test.app-display&/DetailView/idOfSupplier

```
sap.ushell.Container.getService("CrossApplicationNavigation").toExternal({
target: {
      semanticObject: `test.app&/,
      action:"DetailView/${idOfSupplier}`"
    }});
});
```

But instead i get http://localhost:4004/index.html#test.app-display&**-**/DetailView/idOfSupplier
I get an `-` in front of `/DetailView` due to the usage of "action" property.

Any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: Tags "cap" and "launchpad" removed as their tag info describe completely different topics, replaced with "sap-fiori" and tag SAP BTP. Tag "sap" is ambiguous/should not be used.